# Essential in Azure the same for all App Services

Tags: git, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

So I have 3 app services within Azure and I went to add Git deployment username and whatnot for a new app service (all these are basically just web apps), but now, all the app services contain the same ftp hostname, git clone url, etc.... Should they not be different? How do I correct this behavior? These are all under the same resource group, but are different app services for different sites, etc....

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP hostname is for the App Service Worker pool running your **App Service Plan**. So all the apps running on same plan share the FTP hostname.

But the Git clone URLs should definitely be different.

Comment: Do I need to add additional deployment slots?

Comment: Deployment slots are essentially just like another Web App in the same App Service Plan, just linked to another Web App so they can be swapped. It would not help for your problem I think. If indeed the git clone URL is same in all your Web Apps, it sounds more like a question for Azure Support than Stack Overflow.